# Handle emitting elements to a queue sequentially using fs2 Stream Scala

Tags: scala, stream, queue, scheduled-tasks, fs2

Sequential processing in a queue.
There are various methods in `fs2.Stream` for managing how elements are emitted.  `fixedRate, fixedDelay, awakeEvery, awakeDelay`. I want a sequential processing. for instance, No elements are pushed into the queue until the element inside it is pulled.

I have found that fixedDelay methods enables doing this but when I have used it It does not work as It expected.
Here is what I have tried :

```
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp, Timer}
import fs2._
import fs2.concurrent.Queue

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Random
class Tst(q1: Queue[IO, (Double, IO[Long])])(
  implicit timer: Timer[IO]
) {

  val streamData = Stream.emit(1)
  val scheduledStream = Stream.fixedDelay[IO](10.seconds) >> streamData

  def storeInQueue: Stream[IO, Unit] = {
    scheduledStream
      .evalTap(n => IO.delay(println(s"Pushing $n to Queue")))
      .map { n =>
        val entryTime =
          timer.clock.realTime(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        (n.toDouble, entryTime)
      }
      .through(q1.enqueue)
  }
  def getFromQueue: Stream[IO, Unit] = {
    q1.dequeue
      .evalTap(_ => timer.sleep(Random.between(10, 30).seconds))
      .map { n =>
        val exitTime =
          timer.clock.realTime(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        (n._1, exitTime)
      }
      .evalMap(n => IO.delay(println(s"Pulling from queue $n")))
  }
}

object Five2 extends IOApp {

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val program = for {
      q <- Queue.bounded[IO, (Double, IO[Long])](1)
      b = new Tst(q)
      _ <- b.storeInQueue.compile.drain.start

      _ <- b.getFromQueue.compile.drain

    } yield ()
    program.as(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```

I'm getting this :

```
Pushing 1 to Queue
Pushing 1 to Queue
Pulling from queue (1.0,IO$301748227)
Pushing 1 to Queue
Pulling from queue (1.0,IO$914911384)
Pushing 1 to Queue
Pulling from queue (1.0,IO$1022209005)
Pushing 1 to Queue
Pushing 1 to Queue
Pulling from queue (1.0,IO$1801897948)
```

The expected output :

```
Pushing 1 to Queue
Pulling from queue (1.0,IO$1022209005)
Pushing 1 to Queue
Pulling from queue (1.0,IO$1801897948)
Pushing 1 to Queue
Pulling from queue (1.0,IO$1801897948)
```

Comment: The problem is where you are printing. The program is working as you expected, the next `push` to the **Queue** is being blocked until the next `pull` is being called. However, because you print just before pushing, the second print is made before the `pull`.

Comment: Thank youu. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez what would be your advice to improve my codeing skills ? specially for scala

Comment: Not sure what do you mean.